# Webhook verification

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webhooks

I'm trying to write a webhook receiver in asp.net mvc api.

But the problem is that the webhook initialize app require a strange verification method. They need me to add the following code in order to verify and allow me to add my URL in their dashboard.

```
  `<?php if (isset($_GET['zd_echo'])) exit($_GET['zd_echo']); ?>`
```

What do you suggest I can achieve it in asp.net. I tried following so far. (It worked in postman but they couldn't verify it.)

```
// POST api/<controller>
    public string Post([FromBody]CallNotification value, string zd_echo)
    {
        if( zd_echo != null && zd_echo != "")
        {
            return value.zd_echo;
        }
        else
        {
           this.AddCall(value);
            return value.status_code;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first I'm not a Php dev. Second, there are a lot of assumptions here, so this is solely based on what you've posted.

- `<?php if (isset($_GET['zd_echo'])) exit($_GET['zd_echo']); ?>`

  - [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) are **`HTTP GET`** variables from `query string`. So it's a `GET` request vs your API's expected `POST`
  - The code is echoing the value of `zd_echo` key in a `query string`, e.g. `http://example.com/?zd_echo=foo` will echo/respond with `foo` **if it is set** [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Based on the above assumptions:

```
// Just echo the value of the zd_echo key in the query string if it's set
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] string zd_echo)
{
    //if not set/null return HTTP 200
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(zd_echo))
        return Ok();

    return ResponseMessage(new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        Content = new StringContent(zd_echo)
    });
}
```

So a request to: `http://example.com/api/webhook?zd_echo=bar` will:

- respond with `bar` as,
- `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Otherwise, something like `http://example.com/api/webhook?zd_echo` will just respond with `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

Hth.